Publish Test Results to match Test Plan, Test Suite, and Test Cases defined in the Test Plan section
I’ve automated tests that run against various configurations (like different OS versions). The pipeline that deploys these runs publishes the results in JUnitResults.xml format as Artifacts. I recently discovered the Test Plan tab in Azure DevOps and noticed that the pipeline results (JUnitResults.xml) are published in the Test Plans -> Runs section.
In the Test Plan section, I’ve set up all the supported configurations, created a Test Plan, a Test Suite, and test cases based on my automated tests.
My question is: How can I associate the test results published by the pipeline with the Test Plan, its test suite, test cases, and the configurations I’ve created in the Azure DevOps Test Plan section?
I tried to modify the publish task in the pipeline to specify the test plan Id and test suite but it was not successful.
I also ensured that the test suite and test cases titles are matching both in the test results and test plan section in Azure DevOps but still cannot see any association between the test results and test plan.
